# Listbox inside ScrollViewer height calculations

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, grid, scrollviewer

When I place a ListBox inside a ScrollViewer, if I do not define a Height attribute for the ListBox, it doesn't scroll (aside from bouncing up and down a bit), so elements off the screen are inaccessible. If I set the Height attribute on the ListBox to the actual height it takes up on the screen, it scrolls perfectly. If I don't get the Height exactly right, it doesn't scroll properly, e.g. I might not be able to reach the bottom elements in the list.

When placing other elements in the single column LayoutRoot Grid above and below the ScrollViewer/ListBox, I set the RowDefinition.Height="Auto" on all rows except the ScrollViewer's, which gets "*". The Grid appears to properly allocate space accordingly. Except now I don't know a priori how much space the ScrollViewer/ListBox takes up.

Part A: Why should I have to set the Height on the ListBox, doesn't its (virtual) height vary with the number of elements?

Part B: It appears I have to manually lay out the Grid row heights, then manually re-do them if a fontsize or other style change is called for. Is that the case? That approach seems bogus.

Comment: It gets even weirder: What I want is a list with a few popular items at the top, an unselectable line, then the full list below. If I put those three elements in a grid contained in a ScrollView, only the bottom ListBox scrolls, not the whole grid. That's completely nonintuitive. Wrong, even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problems are caused because you've got a ListBox inside a ScrollViewer. Don't do this.

The Listbox contains an internal ScrollViewer and will (normally) grow to the available space.

By essentially having a ScrollViewer inside a ScrollViewer it doesn't know which one should grow to fit available space and how they should scroll relative to one another.

Let us know what you're trying to do. There is a better way to do it.

Comment: Ah. If anyone mentioned that in some of the other fora, I missed it. With that fix, it's doing almost what I want.

Ideally, I'd like to put a divider (I'm using a border with minimal height) inside a ListBox to separate two sections, instead of using two lists separated by a border. The reason I've done it the latter way is that the ListBox allows the border to be selected. I can ignore the selected event for it, but the animation/highlighting still happens.

Comment: I'm going to mark the original question as answered, though. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, figured out the border issue via using ListBoxItems in code-behind.

Comment: I disagree - I find that the ScrollViewer within the ListBox doesn't scroll smoothly but snaps to the height of the individual items, this can cause issues when the height can be larger. Setting the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Hidden and encapsulating the ListBox in a ScrollViewer does resolve this an allow smooth scrolling. I haven't looked into whether it's possible to enable smooth scrolling on the ListBox ScrollViewer as that is possibly a more elegant solution.